# creating a function that converts an array to uppercase

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

so lets say I created an array that is ..

```
let foods = ['oranges', 'pears', 'peaches]
```

now I want to create a function that allows me to select any of the elements and convert it to uppercase letters how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you could do something like:

```
let foods = ["oranges", "pears", "peaches"];

function uppercase(array, index) {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i == index) {
      console.log(array[i]);
      result = array[i].toUpperCase();
      return result;
    }
  }
}

result = uppercase(foods, 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const foods = ['oranges', 'pears', 'peaches']

const toUpper = s => s.toUpperCase()

console.log(foods.map(toUpper))
```